# Translucent White Looks Gray (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I am using Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on GLKit.
My game involves bubbles and things inside of them. To 
achieve this effect I have the Background of the Bubble 
and another image to create the shine.

What I want it to look like

[image]

My problem is when I do this it turns out to look like 
an ugly grey. I'm at a bit of a loss here so 
any help would be appreciated.

What it looks like

[image]

Comment: Below I see only gray boxes :P

Comment: Sorry I can't add pictures :(

Comment: http://imgur.com/ or something like that and paste a link?

Comment: Translucent white WILL look gray over a black background. Either change the background, or set it to the solid color you want to achieve.

Comment: It's not on a black background though it's on yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out what I just changed glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 

to glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: It's right approach. For more details search for `premultiplied alpha` in PNG image

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: you need to "brighten" the colors you are blending, by adding some grey to them, i.e. something to the effect of `outcol = incol + vec4(0.2,0.2,0.2,0)` in your shader (or outside your shader if that is more convenient)

Comment: Sorry I'm using GLKit so how would you add it outside of the shader?